# Getting error: Cannot reshape array of size 122304 into shape (52,28,28)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, reshape

I'm trying to reshape a numpy array as:

```
data3 = data3.reshape((data3.shape[0], 28, 28))
```

where `data3` is:

```
[[54 68 66 ..., 83 72 58]
 [63 63 63 ..., 51 51 51]
 [41 45 80 ..., 44 46 81]
 ..., 
 [58 60 61 ..., 75 75 81]
 [56 58 59 ..., 72 75 80]
 [ 4  4  4 ...,  8  8  8]]
```

`data3.shape` is `(52, 2352 )`

But I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 122304 into shape (52,28,28)
Exception TypeError: TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",) in <function _remove at 0x10b6477d0> ignored
```

What is happening and how to fix this error?

UPDATE:

I'm doing this to obtain `data3` that is being used above:

```
def image_to_feature_vector(image, size=(28, 28)):

    return cv2.resize(image, size).flatten()

data3 = np.array([image_to_feature_vector(cv2.imread(imagePath)) for imagePath in imagePaths])
```

imagePaths contains paths to all the images in my dataset. I actually want to convert the data3 to a `flat list of 784-dim vectors`, however the

```
image_to_feature_vector
```

function converts it to a 3072-dim vector!!

Comment: 52*28*28 = 40768, while your array has 52*2352 = 122304 elements. You need to pick compatible sizes.

Comment: 2352 = 28*28*3.  Perhaps you want `data3 = data3.reshape((data3.shape[0], 28, 28, 3))`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Please see my updated question as to what I need to do.

Comment: what is the shape of `cv2.imread(imagePath)`?

Comment: @akilat90 It is of the form: (1030, 858, 3)

Comment: You can't perform this transformation because 1030*858*3 is not equal to 784. See my answer based on the assumption that the number of elements are equal before and after.

Answer (score 6):

You can reshape the  numpy matrix arrays such that before(a x b x c..n) = after(a x b x c..n). i.e the total elements in the matrix should be same as before, In your case, you can transform it such that transformed data3 
has shape  (156, 28, 28) or simply :-

```
import numpy as np

data3 = np.arange(122304).reshape(52, 2352 )

data3 = data3.reshape((data3.shape[0]*3, 28, 28))

print(data3.shape)
```

Output is of the form

```
[[[     0      1      2 ...,     25     26     27]
  [    28     29     30 ...,     53     54     55]
  [    56     57     58 ...,     81     82     83]
  ..., 
  [   700    701    702 ...,    725    726    727]
  [   728    729    730 ...,    753    754    755]
  [   756    757    758 ...,    781    782    783]]
  ...,
[122248 122249 122250 ..., 122273 122274 122275]
  [122276 122277 122278 ..., 122301 122302 122303]]]
```

Comment: What is 156 in (156, 28, 28)??

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but then when I do (trainData, testData, trainLabels, testLabels) = train_test_split(
    data3 / 255.0, labels, test_size=0.33), I get this error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [156, 52] on that line.

Answer (score 0):

First, your input image's number of elements should match the number of elements in the desired feature vector.

Assuming the above is satisfied, the below should work:

```py
# Reading all the images to a one numpy array. Paths of the images are in the imagePaths
data = np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(imagePaths[i])) for i in range(len(imagePaths))])

# This will contain the an array of feature vectors of the images
features = data.flatten().reshape(1, 784)
```

Comment: Getting error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 52 into shape (1,784)

Comment: @akrama81 Do your images satisfy the mentioned requirement? (Total elements == 784)

Comment: If you mean feature vectors, then it's 2352. How to convert to 784?

Comment: @akrama81 I didn't get this: `If you mean feature vectors, then it's 2352. How to convert to 784?` What I said was that your input image should have a total number of `784`(exactly) pixels if you want to convert it to a `[1,784]` vector.