# Cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (1,128,128,1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, keras

I am taking image as a form input from the user and then trying to resizing it to (1,128,128,1) but getting 
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (1,128,128,1)`

Following is the snippet for taking image and then resizing it to (1,128,128,1)-

```
def predit():
   im = Image.open(request.files['image'])
   image_data = np.asarray(im)
   input_img_flatten = cv2.resize(image_data,(128,128)).flatten()
   im2arr = np.reshape(input_img_flatten,(1,128,128,1))
   return str(np.argmax(model.predict(im2arr)))
```

When I am not taking input image as a form input but just opening it from my desktop using the following approach , my code is running correctly.

```
model = load_model('./latest.hdf5')
img = cv2.imread('/Users/swastik/thapar/test/test2.jpg',0)
input_img_flatten = cv2.resize(img,(128,128).flatten()
im2arr = np.array(input_img_flatten).reshape((1, 128, 128, 1)) 
print(np.argmax(model.predict(im2arr)))
```

How to do it?

I have seen this answer [Getting error: Cannot reshape array of size 122304 into shape (52,28,28)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408496/getting-error-cannot-reshape-array-of-size-122304-into-shape-52-28-28) but the op hasn't accepted any of the answers and even I am not able to understand the given solutions correctly.

Complete Code-

```
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

model = load_model('./latest.hdf5')
im = Image.open('Anyimageinyourfolder.jpg')
image_data = np.asarray(im)
input_img_flatten = cv2.resize(image_data,(128,128)).flatten()
im2arr = np.array(input_img_flatten).reshape((1, 128, 128, 1))
print(np.argmax(model.predict(im2arr)))
```

Comment: My intention is to take the input image which can be of any dimension and reshape it to (1,128,128,1) which I am able to do when I am not taking the form input .The image is same in both cases.

Comment: then how I am able to do using the second approach when I am not taking input from form

Comment: @BradSolomon Yeah, I was thinking the same thing, but notice the `resize` just before the reshape...

Comment: @Bing Can you, please make a [mcve] that will let us reproduce the problem?

Comment: I need to upload the hdf5 file for it , would it be right if I upload it?

Comment: This is the google drive link for the model- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rti2ct0MQz4pSq4dNbZ-WA6to_5vvq1p

Comment: For reference, 921600 = 2¹² × 3² × 5²

Comment: When I try that here, I get "array of size 49152" rather than the 921600. This is easily explained, since it's exactly 3x128x128 -- i.e. you loaded a 3 channel image and left it as such. However, the other variant (which uses `cv2.imread`) forces the image to be loaded as grayscale (that's what the magic number `0` means). The PIL equivalent of this would be something like `Image.open(request.files['image']).convert('L')`.

Comment: Thanks , it worked but using PIL equivalent is messing with the desired output. Are both cv2.imread and PIL renders image same as it is giving the wrong output while using PIL equivalent

Comment: @DanMašek , the other issue is also resolved .Apparently there is a difference between how open cv and PIL reads the images , PIL if length is greater than the width changes the image to landscape mode .

Comment: @Bing Great, glad you figured it out. In this case, you can probably ditch PIL, as you only seem to use it to open the image. OpenCV `imread`/`imdecode` should be sufficient in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what is causing your issue. Assuming the images are grey-scale (single color channel) like they are in your example, maybe this code helps:

```
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, (128,128))
img = img[np.newaxis,:,:,np.newaxis]
print(img.shape)
>>> (1, 128, 128, 1)
```

Also, if you are only predicting one image, you still need to index the returned predictions like so: `print(np.argmax(model.predict(img)[0]))`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to take image as a form input , i have figured out how to do it using the cv.imread approach